# Javascript ajax call post incomplete data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, web-crawler, mason

I had an unusual situation occuring in production while doing a asynchronous ajax post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Mylib.defined('jQuery', function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            'type':    'POST',
            'url':   '/my/url.html',
            'async':   true,
            'cache':   false,
            'global':  false,
            'data':    {
                    'param1': 'value1' ,
                    'param2': 'value2'
            }
      });
  });
```

**Mylib.defined(functionality,callback())** wait for the functionality to load and then triggers the callback function.

/my/url.m is mason file and takes two parameters out of which 'param1' has been made essential, that it should be present in posted data.

Contents of **/my/url.m**

```
<%args>
    param1
    param2 => undef
</%args>
<%perl>
   -----
 </%perl>
<%args>
```

**Problem**

I was having a sense that since we are posting JSON data from our ajax call(see JS above), whose key param1 is hard coded(Though value1 is dynamic), I will never get into a situation where endpoint(mason file) won't be passed the param1 which is essential. But to my surprise there were hell lot of cases where param1 was not passed to mason file. I was not able to get this.Can someone help me here?

Can web-crawlers hit the url /my/url.html without any arguments?

Comment: Check your browser's console (Chrome => Network) what kind of data were sent. So you can find out if it is a client or server problem. Then we can take a closer look.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that, if crawlers can hit the url without any argument to /my/url.html